# Problem with Internet access on kvm

Tags: linux, centos, kvm, internet, suse

i have a question about How to enable Internet access on kvm. I have situation like that: 
Internet traffic going through external firewall, I have ports 5000-5004 forwarded to my machine (interface em1). On kvm I have virtual interface which NAT that em1 to my kvm guest.

On host machine I have iptables setup:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 5001 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.100.170:22

iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp -d 192.168.100.170 --dport 5001 -j SNAT --to-source EXTERNAL-IP
```

Connection with ssh works correctly (ssh to port 5000 connect me to host, ssh to 5001 connect me to guest). I can ping from guest to host, but I cant install anything from repository, ping anything, etc.
My host is **sles12** and guest kvm is **centos 7**
Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `SNAT` in the wrong direction. There is no need for it with incoming connections. You need it when the VM initiates a connection:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp -s 192.168.100.170 -j SNAT --to-source EXTERNAL-IP
```

where `EXTERNAL-IP` is the address of `em1`.

In general it helps a lot to use `tcpdump` on both interfaces. Then you see whether the packets have the correct addresses.